# Redis master vs slave reads and failover

Tags: redis

I am currently using two redis nodes where one is replicating another. Other than that, I've tried searching google/redis documentation for clear cut ways of having my Ruby on Rails application sends reads to the slave and writes to the master. Also tips for a failover would be great. I am not sure if this is a standard way of running Redis and if I am looking at it the wrong way. The two problems I am trying to solve are simply redundancy and higher throughput.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the documentation for "redis sentinel", it's a new monitoring and failover solution.